# camel-http4 2.22 - toD not working

Tags: java, apache-camel

The camel dynamic uri in dynamic route (toD) seem to have stopped working for me after migrating to 2.22.0 (from 2.16.5). The test route that demonstrates the issue:

```
<route>
    <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=1000"/>
    <setHeader headerName="SMSURI">
        <constant>localhost:9090/</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <toD uri="https4://${header.SMSURI}?throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
</route>
```

And I get the following exception:

```
2018-08-11T14:41:07,770 | INFO  | Camel (testContext) thread #27 - timer://foo | route5                           | 160 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.22.0 | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find endpoint with scheme https4
    at org.apache.camel.runtimecatalog.AbstractCamelCatalog.endpointProperties(AbstractCamelCatalog.java:529)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpSendDynamicAware.prepare(HttpSendDynamicAware.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

I know there are two alternative ways for dynamic uri, one is to set Exchange.HTTP_URI and then use the static route 'to' with an arbitrary url, the second one is to use reciepientList. However, I do not like the first option of using 'to', as I need to set an arbitrary url. I am currently using the second option, receipientList something like this (Note that setHeader is used here only for demo. The url is dynamically retrieved and set in a processor class in my project):

```
<route>
    <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=1000"/>
    <setHeader headerName="SMSURI">
        <constant>localhost:9090/</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <recipientList>
        <simple>https4://${header.SMSURI}?throwExceptionOnFailure=false</simple>
    </recipientList>
</route>
```

and this works. However, I really liked the toD option.

Also, camel website says:

> Dynamic To - out of the box
>
> From Camel 2.16 onwards there is a new  which is a dynamic to.
>   See more details at Message Endpoint.

http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Can any one help me understand whether the support has been removed for toD with http4? Or this is a bug?

PS: I am running this from within a Karaf 4.2 container inside OSGI bundle, using blueprint xml.

Comment: Make sure, you have upgraded `camel-http4` dependency to version `2.22.0`. All components must be always imported with same version as `camel-core`.

Comment: Yes all components are for same version. In Karaf, once you add camel repository of a specific version, all components will also be installed for the same version. It was a fresh Karaf installation with no Camel features, then I installed 2.22.0

Comment: We fixed a bug on 2.22.0 that goes into 2.22.1 about issue in toD. You can use recipientList as workaround.

Comment: Thank you Claus! appreciate it. Using recipientList at the moment. Will take 2.22.1 when its out.

Comment: Hi praveenp, we have the same problem. How did you solve it without ToD?

Comment: You need to use reciepientList. Check the question, I have given example for using recipientList instead of toD. Even though I have shown constant header in the above example, you can set any header dynamically and use that in the https4:// url in the recipientLIst.

Comment: Sorry about the late comment, but this is still an issue in 2.23. Did you not add the fix in 2.23, @ClausIbsen

Comment: After searching through code, I can see that catalog feature was added sometime after 2.16, and toD seems to be dependent on catalog to load properties from json for the http component. Even though I have not tried this yet, this problem should be solved by installing the camel-catalog feature in osgi container like karaf, or by including it in the maven dependencies like any other camel component. I am unable to find any documentation of this dependency, all I could find was a small section in the camel tooling here: [link](https://camel.apache.org/tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting the component inside a header that I used in the toD.
Example:

```
<route>
    <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=1000"/>
    <setHeader headerName="SMSURI">
        <constant>https4://localhost:9090/</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <toD uri="${headers.SMSURI}" />
</route>
```